# How to associate a file type within Wine with a native application?

Tags: wine, file-association

For example, I want all avi files to be associated with mplayer **in Wine**

```
mplayer /home/user/myvideo.avi
```

**Edit from Oli:** I believe this this actually the inverse of what most people would assume from the original title. Unless I'm mistaken the user is using Total Commander in Wine and would like to launch a Linux-native player on the path. If I'm wrong, just rollback this edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Wine page has some detail on this](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-e03d797155ac6e9d8176f045acbdeebc28ad33d4).

First you need `winepath` to translate the path. This will make the script and give it permission to run:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin/
echo '#!/bin/sh' > ~/bin/run_linx_program
echo '$1 "`wine winepath -u "$2"`"' >> ~/bin/run_linx_program
chmod a+x ~/bin/run_linx_program
```

Then you'd save something like this to a file called `association.reg`:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.avi]
@="AVIfile"
"Content Type"="video/x-msvideo"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AVIfile\Shell\Open\command]
@="/bin/sh run_linx_program mplayer \"%1\""
```

Then run `regedit association.reg` to add the association to Wine's registry.

Note: this is adapted from the Wine page. I got the mime-type from within Linux (`file --mime-type an_avi.avi`). Wine may treat AVI files differently.

Comment: ... or use `@="c:\windows\system32\winebrowser.exe \"%1\""` as the command. Its a wine builtin that translates the path and launches the file using `xdg-open`. So, provided that `mplayer` is already configured outside wine to handle avi files, its a more generic solution (and no scripting or sudo needed)