# Why don't those winepath commands work?

Tags: command-line, bash, wubi

I tried code from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21864/how-to-associate-a-file-type-within-wine-with-a-native-application/21869#21869) and for some reason they do not work, why and how to fix them?

```
a@ubuntu:~$ echo "#!/bin/sh" > ~/bin/run_linx_program
bash: !/bin/sh": event not found
a@ubuntu:~$ echo "$1 "\`wine winepath -u \"$2\"\`\"" >> ~/bin/run_linx_program
> ?
> ^C
a@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the original answer (and I've tested it this time):

```
mkdir -p ~/bin/
echo '#!/bin/sh' > ~/bin/run_linx_program
echo '$1 "`wine winepath -u "$2"`"' >> ~/bin/run_linx_program
chmod a+x ~/bin/run_linx_program
```

I forgot that ! gets interpreted inside `"`s. I should have used `'`s. `!` starts a history substitution match and that wasn't what I was going for.

Answer (score 1):

! has a special meaning in bash:

> When  the  command history expansion facilities are being used (see HISTORY EXPANSION below), the history expansion character, usually !,
>   must be quoted to prevent history expansion.

There are two ways to prevent history exspansion, either by escaping the `!` with a backslash, or by using single quotes:

```
a@ubuntu:~$ echo "#\!/bin/sh" > ~/bin/run_linux_program
a@ubuntu:~$ echo '#!/bin/sh' > ~/bin/run_linux_program
```

In complex constructs, try to avoid the `"` (double quote) char and use the single one instead (`'`):

```
echo "$1" '"$(wine winepath -u "'$2'")"' >> ~/bin/run_linux_program
```

I've replaced the backticks by `$(` and `)` to make the line more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a round-about way of doing things. The first like creates a file and writes `#!/bin/sh` to it, the second one appends something else to the file.

- To get this working

  1. Create the directory `bin` in your home directory, either in Nautilus or by typing

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/bin
     ```
  2. Create a new file `~/bin/run_linx_program` (where `~` is shorthand for "your home directory") and put these lines into it:

     ```
     #!/bin/bash
     $1 "`wine winepath -u "$2"`"
     ```

     You can create the file by doing `nano ~/bin/run_linx_program`, or you can use the Text Editor.
  3. Run `chmod a+x ~/bin/run_linux_program` to make the file executable, alternatively you can right click the file, open the properties, go to Permissions and set 'executable'.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you actually use or need history expansion, I recommend just turning it off by adding the line

```
set +H
```

in your `~/.bashrc`. I've done that and am quite happy to never be bothered by `event not found` messages again.

Regardless, history expansion is only enabled for interactive shells, so it won't affect scripts.