# How to associate all file types within Wine with its corresponding native application?

Tags: wine, scripts, mime-type, file-association

This is easily done for a *single* file type, as answered in [How to associate a file type within Wine with a native application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21864), by creating a `.reg` for the desired filetype. But this is for AVI only. I use some wine apps (uTorrent, Soulseek, Eudora, to name a few) that can launch a wide range of files. Email attachments, for example, can be JPG, DOC, PDF, PPS... its impossible (and not desirable) to track down all possible file types that one may receive in an email or download in a torrent.

So I neeed a solution to be more generic and broad. I need the file association to honor whatever native app is currently configured. And I want this to be done for *all* file types configured in my system.

I've already figured out how to make the solution generic. Simply replacing the launched app in `.reg` for `winebrowser`, like this:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf]
@="PDFfile"
"Content Type"="application/pdf"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PDFfile\Shell\Open\command]
@="C:\\windows\\system32\\winebrowser.exe \"%1\""
```

Ive tested this and it works correctly. Since winebrowser uses `xdg-open` as a backend, and converts my windows path to a Unix one, the correct (Linux) app is launched.

So I need a "batch" updater to wine's registry, sort of a `wine-update-associations` script that I can run whenever a new app is installed. Maybe a tool that can:

- List all Mime Types types in my system *that have a default, **installed** app associated*
- Extract all the needed info (glob, mime type, etc)
- Generate the .REG file in the above format

The tricky part is: i've searched a LOT to find info about how association is done in Ubuntu 10.10 onwards, and documentation is scarce and confusing, to say the least. Freedesktop.org has no complete spec, and even Gnome docs are obsolete. So far I've gathered **4** files that contain association info, but im clueless on which (or why) to use, or how to use them to generate the `.reg` file:

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
~/.local/share/applications/miminfo.cache
/usr/share/applications/miminfo.cache
/etc/gnome/defaults.list
```

Any help, script or explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Years later, I've made a small utility that scans MIME database (both system and user) and register *all* known native mime-types in Windows registry.

It uses `xdg-open` to open a file if there is a default (native) application for that
mime type, otherwise uses `packagekit` to search for a package that can handle
that file (just like what Nautilus does). So my initial requirement of registering only extensions that have an installed, native application was not needed anymore. However, an early version of the script did filter only such types. The snippet that made it possible was:

```
perl -e '
    use strict; use warnings;
    use File::MimeInfo::Magic; use File::MimeInfo::Applications;
    while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
      chomp($line);
      my ($ext, $mime) = (split/\t/, $line);
      my ($def, @apps) = mime_applications_all($mime);
      print "$line\n" if ($def || @apps)
    }'
```

By default my script only registers native types that have no handler in windows
registry, but it can also override such associations (so, for example, jpeg
files are opened in native viewer instead of the default Gecko wine browser).
It can also ignore some extensions even if they have no handler in windows.

It tries its best to be winemenubuilder-friendly, meaning all associations it
creates is not published as native associations (or as x-wine-extension
mimetypes) by winemenubuilder, which would be ugly and potentially cause loops.
This is very tricky and not yet perfect, specially with mixed-case extensions
(.C and .c for example)

That said, I hope this script is helful for everyone:

https://github.com/MestreLion/wine-tools/blob/master/wine-import-extensions

Improvements welcome!

Comment: your script says it succeeded, but nothing in wine changed for me. No big problem, I found another workaround in the wine app `Everything` itself, but I just wanted to inform you

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

There is a [wine bug about this](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12464) - which is more of an improvement than a bug. The point is to have `ShellExecute` call `xdg-open`, and if not found, look for gnome and kde defaults. You should be able to apply the patch and finally have the magic :-).
This solution is *cleaner* as it does not need messing with the registry.

To be more complete here is how to [patch and compile wine from source](http://wiki.winehq.org/Patching).

**END EDIT**

I update the wine registry with the script below to add a list of common file types.
You can extend the list to add more types.
It makes use of `/usr/bin/gnome-open` in the `gstart.exe` file so it **won't work for non-gnome desktops as is**.

Put this in `conf_wine.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

SRC=~
WINE=~/.wine
REG=$WINE/system.reg
GSTART=gstart.exe
GSTART_TARGET=$WINE/drive_c
EXE_TARGET=$WINE/drive_c/windows
FNKEY=/tmp/"key"$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S)".reg"

[ -e $FNKEY ] && { echo "temporary key file exists..try again"; exit 1; }

echo "copying gstart.exe"
cp $SRC/$GSTART $GSTART_TARGET
chmod +x $GSTART_TARGET

echo "backing up the registry"
cp $REG $REG.$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S).old

echo "setting new wine registry keys"
for i in http doc docx ppt pptx xls xlsx odt ods xml txt pdf odt svg zip ; do {
    echo "setting $i"
key='[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.'$i']
@="'$i'file"
"Content Type"="application/'$i'"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\'$i'file\Shell\Open\command]
@="C:\\gstart.exe \"%1\""'
    echo "$key" > $FNKEY
    regedit $FNKEY
}
done

echo "done"
```

The `gstart.exe` is a bash script..and is the bridge to both worlds:

```
#!/bin/bash

OPEN_HANDLER=/usr/bin/gnome-open
# logging, optional
LOG=$HOME/.wine/gstart.exe-log.$(id -u -n)
echo "[ $(date) ] $# argument(s) received: '$@'" > $LOG

# convert the path
RESULT=$(winepath "$@" 2> /dev/null)
echo "$OPEN_HANDLER $RESULT" >> $LOG
TMP=$TMPDIR
TEMP=$TMPDIR

# finally open the file
$OPEN_HANDLER "$RESULT"
```

**Notes:**

1. copy `gstart.exe` in your current working directory before running
   `conf_wine.sh` as it will copy it to the `.wine` folder.
2. the folder locations can be changed, e.g. `gstart.exe` doesn't have to
   sit in `c:\`.
3. does no magic: new types have to be added manually. You could improve it to read the Linux files (mimeapps.list, ..) and update the wine registry if then needed.
4. tested to work at least in wine1.4.

Wine FAQ: [How do I associate a native program with a file type in Wine?](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-bc5b677c29daa2cd16b83bca8c88f31b2341cb98)

Comment: +1 for the effort, but this hardly solve my problem.
First, there is little point using `gnome-open` over `xdg-open`, which I already mentioned in the question, and is far more portable.
Second, hardcoding a few file extensions is insufficient for me: as I said, *"I need the file association to honor whatever native app is currently configured. And I want this to be done for all file types configured in my system."* And I'm aware this is tricky. It's the "magic" you mentioned in your note #3 that I'm interested in ;)

Comment: I guess I read your question a bit too fast the first.. I saw you are using  xdg-open and I'll change it in my scripts.
About the magic: one way would be to read iterate over all items in the mime files instead of having. But then you will have to run it every time you update your system as new extensions might have been added. That does not happen every day though.

Comment: Or even brutally set up a cronjob for the registry update..only modifying the registry if the mimes have been updated.

Comment: The tricky part is not *when* to update the registry, but *how*, or, more precisely, update for which file extentions? I don't know how to consistently parse the mime database to retrieve all the extensions *that have a default, **installed** app associated*. Or, as you said: how to *read iterate over all items in the mime files*? There are some mime types in my `mimeapps.lst` that I don't have installed here, and some point back to a Wine app (which would cause infinite loops)

Comment: Sorry about the English mistakes in my first comment, I edited it and it got messed up a bit..
Please read my EDIT in the answer, there you have the magic as all files are taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

I have gathered Info all over the place and have found the following to work:

I have created a file called 
~/.wine/drive_c/gstart.exe

with the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
OPEN_HANDLER=/usr/bin/xdg-open
# logging, optional
LOG=$HOME/.wine/gstart.exe-log.$(id -u -n)
echo "[ $(date) ] $# argument(s) received: '$@'" > $LOG
# convert the path
RESULT=$(winepath "$@" 2> /dev/null)
echo "$OPEN_HANDLER $RESULT" >> $LOG
TMP=$TMPDIR
TEMP=$TMPDIR
# finally open the file
$OPEN_HANDLER "$RESULT"
```

Then :
Created a file called linuxnative.reg in my ~/bin

with the following :

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.doc]
@="linuxnative"
"Content Type"="application/linuxnative"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rtf]
@="linuxnative"
"Content Type"="application/linuxnative"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.odt]
@="linuxnative"
"Content Type"="application/linuxnative"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf]
@="linuxnative"
"Content Type"="application/linuxnative"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tif]
@="linuxnative"
"Content Type"="application/linuxnative"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.doc]
@="linuxnative"
"Content Type"="application/linuxnative"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docx]
@="linuxnative"
"Content Type"="application/linuxnative"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jpg]
@="linuxnative"
"Content Type"="application/linuxnative"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\linuxnative]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\linuxnative\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\linuxnative\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\linuxnative\shell\open\command]
@="c:\\gstart.exe \"%1\""
```

then you do a

regedit linuxnative.reg

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! But a hardcoded list of a few well-known extensions does not solve my problem. Also, the *"info you gathered from all over the place"* seems to be the same info already posted by me and rosch, including a copy-and-paste of his `gstart.exe` script.