# Can Wine and its programs be set to use Ubuntu file manager instead of Wine Explorer?

Tags: wine, filemanager, default-programs

When browsing directories in a Windows program installed in Wine  - like when opening a folder in Foobar2000 -  Wine always opens the Wine explorer:

[image: Open containing folder option in Foobar2000]

---

[image: The wine file manager]

Is it possible to set Wine to open an Ubuntu file manager (e.g Nautilus) instead?

Comment: You "should" be able to replace `usr/bin/winefile`. I haven't tested it though (and I suspect the FM you replace it with would need to accept the path as an argument).

Comment: @hbdgaf - where is the line that specifies the FM in `usr/bin/winefile`?

Comment: fwiw, I believe the window in question is called the file chooser.  I couldn't find anything though

Comment: What file am I editing to change winefile?

Comment: @James   - start your comment with "@" before the name of the user you are addressing

Comment: @cipricus I was addressing you, and it's your answer...

Comment: er, your question I mean. Sorry. @RobotHumans what file am I editing? `/usr/bin/winefile` takes me to the wine filebrowser

Comment: I was looking at a hard replace on disk.  Not a file edit.  I have no idea what file to change pointing to it.

Comment: @RobotHumans Do you have any ideas? Or is there somewhere that the inner mechanisms of winefile will be explained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04** A quick review of the code in `/usr/bin/winefile` indicates that the answer is no. after checking to see if it's called with a directory name it clearly is using wine to launch the file manager regardless.

Excerpt:

```
if [ -x "$appdir/wine" ]; then exec "$appdir/wine" "$appname" "$@"; fi

# finally look in PATH
exec wine "$appname" "$@"
```

Since wine is designed to launch Windows executables It won't launch native apps. I would assume that using wine to launch the file selection routine is necessary in order to insure that the proper parameter is passed after file selection. This opinion is purely based on logic (and the content of /usr/bin/winefile). If you have information to the contrary please comment and share.

Comment: It seems, `winefile` just do the translation of application name or .exe name and handles that to `wine` program to do stuff with that.

Comment: Do you think that the way [Foobar2000 can open the Linux file manager](http://askubuntu.com/a/858496/47206) qualifies as an "information to the contrary" in the sense you ask above?

Comment: @cipricus No I don't. If you look carefully at that answer you will note that it's calling C:\windows\system32\winebrowser.exe to display the directory called. (winebrowser.exe is clearly not a native app and is a part of the [wine library](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=winebrowser.exe&mode=exactfilename&suite=yakkety&arch=any)

Comment: So then can't you just make a script called wine that calls wine for everyting except nautilus/thunar/etc...

Comment: @Dagelf You could certainly try, on the flip side that could easily result in unintended consequences that would make supporting any issues you may have with wine in the future exceedingly difficult, so I wouldn't recommend that course of action.

Answer (score 4):

The most promising approach seems to me to set MIME types for all files of interest. Have a look at [How to associate all file types within Wine with its corresponding native application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51325/how-to-associate-all-file-types-within-wine-with-its-corresponding-native-applic)

Other things I tried, but didn't work:
`/usr/bin/winefile` is a simple wrapper script, you can replace or change it.
For example, to use thunar as your file manager in wine, add after the #comment lines

```
thunar $@
exit
```

You can leave the rest as it is, to be able to undo your changes.

Second approach, not working: looking in `system32` for `winefile.exe` and `explorer.exe`, replacing them with softlinks to thunar. Wine ignores this, even a double-click on this softlinks runs `winefile` instead of thunar.

It seems to me that `winefile` is a builtin of wine. Maybe some registry edits could change wine's behaviour.

Comment: I like this approach

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me - it still opens the Wine file manager when choosing "Open containing folder" or "Locate on disk" in Picasa, instead of Caja (the MATE file manager), which is what I want. Any ideas ?

Comment: @JonasCZ I found a file winefile.exe in ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32. I renamed it to winefile.exe.bak and did   "ln -s /usr/bin/thunar ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/winefile.exe". Surprisingly, it doesn't change anything. Even if I double click this link, winefile instead of thunar is starting. I suspect winefile may be a builtin of wine.

Comment: @JonasCz Edit: There seems to be a twin of winefile.exe called explorer.exe. I did the same (replacing with link  to thunar), and nothing changes. Maybe there has to be an adjustment in the registry to change the behaviour of wine in this case.

Comment: @Lauscher that's not too surprising. See my answer.

Comment: @JonasCz You said something useful. Is it ok to use winefile instead ? or some custom application?

Comment: @Anwar, I'd like something which allows me to open files, move / copy them, and so on. Preferable a naitive file manager (such as Ubuntu's nautilus).

Comment: @JonasCz I saw you've already awarded the bounty. I was trying to suggest replacing the default wine explorer provided by Wine. also it seems you can associate native applications with individual file types, but to open a folder, that is hard even in Windows.

Comment: @Anwar Could you add an answer briefly describing this ?

Comment: @JonasCz I couldn't manage to replace the wine explorer. I fear the explorer is from shell32.dll. But I can associate native application. Do you still suggest adding an answer?

Comment: @JonasCz I've added an answer illustrating how you can associate a native application with a _file type_ in WINE.

Comment: @Anwar - what answer is that?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late! - Is this answer correct/confirmed? @Lauscher says he hasn't checked it before posting, comments contradict it. -  @Lauscher, would you please test and confirm it works, and then post a few more lines of  `/usr/bin/winefile` to illustrate clearly what to do?

Comment: @cipricus, I have tested it, but it does not seem to work. wine ignores a changed `/usr/bin/winefile` and it ignores softlinks to thunar replacing `winefile.exe` and `explorer.exe`. wine seems to use none of these applications. As another approach, one could run `wine regedit` and search for entrys related to file browsing, maybe with keyword`explorer.exe`.

Comment: @cipricus The most promising approach seems to me to set MIME types for all files of interest. Have a look at [How to associate all file types within Wine with its corresponding native application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51325/how-to-associate-all-file-types-within-wine-with-its-corresponding-native-applic)

Comment: The linked question in your comment is very interesting. But your answer, as it stands now, if one considers it without reading the comments, may seem misleading to a newcomer, as it is saying something that is not the case. It should be edited to indicate that the most probable solution will come from the linked question: associating file-types to native applications.

Comment: @cipricus, I've updated my answer with the core discoverys from the comments. The time I wrote it first, the questian had a focal point on `/usr/bin/winefile`, but no longer now.

Answer (score 4):

You can associate folders with the native file manager by saving the following as `fix.reg` and importing it using Wine's regedit. Make sure to back up the registry first.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\folder\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\folder\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\folder\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\windows\\system32\\winebrowser.exe\" -nohome \"%1\""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\folder\shell\open\ddeexec]
```

This works for me to make foobar2000 open the native file manager when using 'Open Containing Folder'

Comment: This works for me (tested with Vortex). This seems like the best solution imo.

Answer (score 2):

i think no. even i have use crossover with enabled "use native browser by default" it still use it's own file browser when i tried to open file from ms. word

[image: wine file manager]

Comment: This might not be true. You can assign native application to wine

Comment: @Anwar - please provide a separate answer under the question with your solution. Even a limited one will be appreciated and awarded a bounty if the case.

Comment: an "open/save file" dialog is very different from an "open file explorer" button. The former will open a built-in dialog while the latter simply asks the system file browser to open a location. [samg](https://askubuntu.com/users/1097260/samg)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1252225/229855) shows how to make wine use the linux-native file browser for "open this location" buttons/links, but I doubt it has any effect on "open/save file" dialogs.